# What is "Request Headers From Upload Stream"

Tags: php, curl, firebug

From firebug:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/OYMrIx2.jpg]

If I want to emulate this request using php-curl , do I have to worry about the request headers from upload stream? What exactly is it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you upload a file, during the HTTP request, there are the standard HTTP request headers which you see, then you get something like:

```
-------------------------------18788734234
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="nonfile_field"

{input field here}
-------------------------------18788734234
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myfile"; filename="somefile.gif"
Content-Type: image/gif

{uploaded file here}
-------------------------------18788734234--
```

Firebug is pulling out these extra request headers that come with file uploads and giving you more information about it. If you do a standard file upload with php-curl, curl will what it needs to do to ensure the upload happens successfully.

Comment: hmm but there isn't any file upload taking place ? just a POST form submission.

Comment: Same goes for a simple form post as well. Just without the extra data for the file.

Comment: I came here looking why firebug is not pulling out anything for FormData request.